# JAVA / How to make an async callback using comletable-future?

Tags: java, android-studio, asynchronous, fetch, completable-future

I am fetching data from dedicated file HttpHandler. It works, I call my class HttpHandler into a fragment named HomeFragment.

What I'd like to do is to use these data in my HomeFragment. I had been adviced to look at completable-futur and async computation.

What I did, I found some article about it. But how to implement that from what I have is  totally blurry.

Any help will be appreciated.

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        HttpHandler req = new HttpHandler();

        // The blurry part => 
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(req.fetchData())
                .thenAccept(Log.d("ok","ok"));

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

**HttpHandler.java**

```
    public class HttpHandler {

    private OkHttpClient httpClient;
    private static final String TAG = "TagActivity";

    public HttpHandler() {
        fetchData();
    }

    private void fetchData() {
        httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/user/rising/0.json")
                .header("Authorization","Client-ID bb0c749c6403fd2")
                .header("User-Agent","epicture")
                .build();

        httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "An error has occurred " + e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONArray items = data.getJSONArray("data");
                    final List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
                    for(int i=0; i<items.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
                        Photo photo = new Photo();
                        if(item.getBoolean("is_album")) {
                            photo.id = item.getString("cover");
                        } else {
                            photo.id = item.getString("id");
                        }
                        photo.title = item.getString("title");
                        photos.add(photo);
                        Log.d(TAG, photo.title);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("JSONerr" , "Something went wrong.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static class Photo {
        String id;
        String title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your code is that `fetchData` returns void and so you have no access to the fetched data, neither synchronous, nor asynchronous.

So most logical way out is to make `fetchData` to return data, and preferrably in asynchronous form, as it is most flexible. The exact type of the returned result may vary, but I choose `CompletableFuture` as a standard:

```
public class HttpHandler {

public HttpHandler() {
    // do not call fetchData() here
}

public CompletableFuture<String> fetchData() {
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/user/rising/0.json")
            .header("Authorization","Client-ID bb0c749c6403fd2")
            .header("User-Agent","epicture")
            .build();
    CompletableFuture<String> result = new CompletableFuture<String>();
    httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            result.completeExceptionally(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            result.complete(response.body().string());
        }
    });
    return result;
}
}
```

All the data processing better to do in `HomeFragment`. First, we keep `HttpHandler`  universal. Second, we do not own computational resources which invoke the callback, so better use them minimally.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HttpHandler req = new HttpHandler();
        CompletableFuture<String> data = req.fetchData();
        try {
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(data.get());  // get() can throw IOException, handled below
            JSONArray items = data.getJSONArray("data");
            final List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
            for(int i=0; i<items.length();i++) {
                JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
                Photo photo = new Photo();
                if(item.getBoolean("is_album")) {
                    photo.id = item.getString("cover");
                } else {
                    photo.id = item.getString("id");
                }
                photo.title = item.getString("title");
                photos.add(photo);
                Log.d(TAG, photo.title);
           }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO Error" , e.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONerr" , e.toString);
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work but I'm gonna look at how you proceed to understand how I can do. 
Thanks

Comment: error: no suitable method found for supplyAsync(CompletableFuture<String>)
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(req.fetchData())

Comment: But I found another way to get my data, I made a callback() method and that work Thank youu

Answer (score 0):

I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/60015763/11560055 is a good solution for your answer. If you have any error with these codes, you can see complete code for this answer [here](https://gist.github.com/ZattWine/c2d7d0c65534508e18739acfa539c273).